# Given the supremum of a set, prove the supremum of a related set

Tags: real-analysis

Let S be a bounded set of positive real numbers, and let T = {s$^2$ : s $\in$ S}.  Set u:= sup S.
Prove that u$^2$ = sup T.

Let S,T be as described.  Let s$^2$ $\in$ T.  Then s $\in$ S and s $\le$ u.  Since s and u are both positive, s$^2$ $\le$ u$^2$ and u$^2$ is an upper bound for T.  Now I need to show that sup T = u$^2$.  My initial approach was to say if u$^2$ = sup T, then for all $\epsilon$ > 0, there exists a t$^2$ $\in$ T such that u$^2$ - $\epsilon$ < t$^2$, but I am having trouble finding a way to show this.  Is the fact that for all $\epsilon$ > 0, there exists a t $\in$ S such that u- $\epsilon$ < t useful or should I be trying a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $u =\sup S$, then $s \le u$ for all $s \in S$ and since $s \ge 0$ we have
$s^2 \le u^2$. Hence $ \sup T \le u^2$.

Now let $0<\epsilon<u$ and choose $s \in S$ such that $s>u-\epsilon$. Then
$s^2 > (u-\epsilon)^2$ and so
$\sup T \ge (u-\epsilon)^2$. Since $\epsilon>0$ can be arbitrarily small, we have
$\sup T = u^2$.